# Does amortization of bond start accumulating on trade date or settlement date?

Tags: portfolio-management

I am sorry if this is not appropriate here. We are building a wealth management system and I really would like to know whether amortization of bond start accumulating on trade date or settlement date according to common accounting standard. 
Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to be much more specific.  Treatment depends on whether you're using IFRS or GAAP and if the bond is held for trading, for sale, or until maturity.

Comment: read your contract

Answer (score 2):

[Global Investment Performance Standards](http://gipsstandards.org/) state that bond amortization performance evaluation starts on trade date rather than settlement date.

On the [attached](http://www.cfapubs.org/doi/pdf/10.2469/ccb.v2010.n5.1) see 1.A.5 which states:

> 1.A.5 For periods beginning on or after 1 January 2005, FIRMS MUST use TRADE DATE ACCOUNTING.
>
> 1.A.6 ACCRUAL ACCOUNTING MUST be used for fixed-income securities and all other investments that earn interest income. The value of
>   fixed-income securities MUST include accrued income.

Answer (score 0):

Trade date accounting means posting trades to positions on trade date, valuing positions inclusive of that day's trades, and posting corporate action entitlements as of ex-dividend date on positions that include trades through and inclusive of the previous business day.  I am in full agreement.

Fixed income securities trade with accrued interest calculated through settlement date.  Recognition of income for bonds starts on settlement date with the first day's income included in the valuation as of the close of business on settlement date.  Bond-pricing discounts future cash flows to settlement date.  The bond price from which market premium is amortized or market discount is accreted is the discounted price on settlement date, therefore amortization and accretion should begin being calculated on settlement date.  The amortization/accretion schedule should terminate on maturity date, unless there are one or more call or put dates.  The amortization schedule dates should be based on how the bond was priced (best, worst, next), which may result in multiple legs, with each leg terminating at that day's call or put price.

When a bond is sold, amortization and accretion are calculated through but exclusive of the settlement date.